# RAML - json schema error

Tags: json, mule, schema, raml

I have included a JSON schema file in RAML.
In the real file, I'm getting an error saying "The included resource schemas/createRecord.json contains an error"

I have validated the JSON file, but it has no errors
when I replaced the file contents with the working file content, still I'm getting the same error.

It seems to be a problem with the file format and not the content.

Can someone help me in identifying the issue?

Comment: Could you please share your RAML code and JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you validated the json schema. Not all validitors are created equal and the trick is to use one that matches mulesoft and I have found http://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-05/markup/json  is the best and when i get an error in mule I get the same error in jsonschemalint